# networkx not giving all shortest paths for weighted graphs

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to find all possible shortest paths

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()
e=[('a', 'b', 2), ('a', 'c', 6), ('b', 'c', 4), ('c', 'e', 5), ('c', 'f', 1)]
paths=nx.shortest_paths(g,'a','c',weight=True)
print('%s' %list(paths))
```

Here is the output:

```
[['a', 'c']]
```

According to weights, **a->b->c is also a shortest path**.

Why it is not coming in output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your code on my laptop.

```
networkx-1.11
Python 2.7.13
```

So I try to use `all_shortest_paths` method,maybe to some extent they're similar.Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
e = [('a', 'b', 2), ('a', 'c', 6), ('b', 'c', 4)]

for i in e:
    G.add_edge(i[1], i[0], weight=i[2])


paths = nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source='a', target='c',weight=True)

print list(paths)
```

I got the same output,and I read the networkx doc about [all_shortest_paths](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths):

- weight

  > (**None or string**, optional (default = None)) – If None, every
  >   edge has weight/distance/cost 1. If a string, use this edge attribute
  >   as the edge weight. Any edge attribute not present **defaults to 1**.

So I suppose that `weight=True` is invalid,so any edge attribute not present **defaults to 1**,that's why you can't get the result you want.

If you modify your code and change `weight=True` to `weight='weight'`.

You will get:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `shortest_paths` use `all_shortest_paths` function.

Try the below code:

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()
g.add_edge('a','b', distance=2)
g.add_edge('a','c', distance=6)
g.add_edge('b','c', distance=4)
g.add_edge('c','e', distance=5)
g.add_edge('c','f', distance=1)
print([p for p in nx.all_shortest_paths(g,source='a',target='c',weight='distance')])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Kindly accept the answer by clicking the tick button to the left of the answer